# How to write array contents into a file?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-writing

I am trying to save the contents of two arrays lists, one of type integer and one of type string, to a file for a school project. here is what i have right now... keep in mind the variable names for the array lists are list for the string array and listquanity for the integer array

```
case ("6"):  
            {
           final String FNAME = ("C:\\Users\\Neil\\Documents\\Eclipse Workspace\\Final Project Market Stocks\\stocks.txt");

            PrintWriter bw = null;
            try 
            {
                bw = new PrintWriter(new File(FNAME));
                for (int g = 0; g<= list.length(); g++){
                    Printwriter.write();
                }

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }finally{
                if (bw != null){
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Saving...");                
        //System.exit(0);   
        break;
```

Comment: What is wrong, specifically, with the code you posted?

Comment: @ScottHunter the issue with it is that the contents of the list will not write the the file. when we press "6" to save it the file remain blank

Comment: Your code does not even compile for 2 reasons : no method write with no argument, and method is not static so can't called on PrintWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `write()` method on the instance you have, this is not a static method, and pass it the different values of your arrays :

```
for (int g = 0; g < list.length(); g++){
    bw.write(list.get(g));
    bw.write(" ");
    bw.write(listquanity.get(g));
    bw.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean to specify that the array's were ArrayLists

Comment: @Squid so they are not arrays at all, this is not the same ;) I've edit

Answer (score 0):

You created an instance of the `PrintWriter` class called `bw` and now you want to write something with it. You need to use `write()` or any method with this instance. Eg: `bw.write("String")`. I suggest you use the `print()` and `println()` methods since these work the same way as the ones from `System.out.println()`, with which you should be familiar.

The code for printing could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
    bw.println(list[i] + ", " + listquanity[i]);
}
```

I hope this helps you! Good luck!

EDIT: if you want to use ArrayList this would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
    bw.println(list.get(i) + ", " + listquanity.get(i));
}
```

The only difference here is that we need to use the `get()` Method of the ArrayList to access the Element.

Comment: hi Mr yellow this seemed to work, however the only thing that saved to the file was null, null? I was wondering if you know why that might happen. thanks!

Comment: This means that the Elements in your ArrayLists are not initialized or, in other words, are null. So the String concatination justs evaluates `list.get(i)` to `null`. I don't have enough information as to why they are not existing. Please look into this.